# It seems that I can *reference a field before it is defined*

Tags: java, static, enums, declaration

```java
public enum MyEnum1 {

    FOO(BAR), BAR(FOO);

    private MyEnum1 other;

    private MyEnum1(MyEnum1 other) {
        this.other = other;
    }

    public MyEnum1 getOther() {
        return other;
    }

}
```

`MyEnum1` generates the error `Cannot reference a field before it is defined`, which is quite understandable, since declaration order matters here. But why does the following compile?

```java
public enum MyEnum2 {

    FOO { public MyEnum2 getOther() { return BAR; } },
    BAR { public MyEnum2 getOther() { return FOO; } };

    public abstract MyEnum2 getOther();

}
```

`FOO` refers to `BAR` before `BAR` is defined, am I wrong?

Comment: Aren't `enum` constants compiled to structures similar to classes? Returning `BAR`, you're actually referring to a type. Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276775/what-does-java-compile-an-enumeration-down-to): _set of valid values is created at type initialization time_

Comment: [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.1) says _The optional class body of an enum constant implicitly defines an anonymous class declaration (§15.9.5) that extends the immediately enclosing enum type._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important JLS parts are [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1) and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.1)

> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the
>   first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> T is a class and an instance of T is created.
>
> T is a class and a static method declared by T is invoked.
>
> A static field declared by T is assigned.
>
> A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant
>   variable (§4.12.4).
>
> T is a top level class (§7.6), and an assert statement (§14.10)
>   lexically nested within T (§8.1.3) is executed.

And

> The optional class body of an enum constant implicitly defines an
>   anonymous class declaration (§15.9.5) that extends the immediately
>   enclosing enum type.

So with

```
FOO { public MyEnum2 getOther() { return BAR; } }, 
BAR { public MyEnum2 getOther() { return FOO; } };
```

you are creating two anonymous classes extending `MyEnum2`.

When `BAR` is eventually reference either when you call `Foo.getOther()` or some other piece of code does `MyEnum2.Bar`, the type will be initialized.

Answer (score 1):

you are creating enum constant with reference to yet undeclared constant in first case. In second case it does not matter because of compilation order, enumeration constants are compiled before enumeration body. I would say this is the reason. If it was not true, compilation would fail earlier because abstract method declaration is defined after the non-abstract method declaration in body of each enum constant.

Good reference - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9

Answer (score 1):

When writing `FOO(BAR)`, you are actually invoking the constructor of `MyEnum1` and therefore `BAR` has to be *evaluated*, which is impossible at that moment since `BAR` hasn't yet been defined.

When writing `FOO {...}`, you are *creating* a new enum constant called `FOO`, but *defining* a new anonymous class. Since the class definition is only *loaded* ('loaded' as in 'ClassLoader') at this point and nothing is yet being *evaluated*, no error occurs. Then, `BAR {...}` is being created, the rest of your program continues, etc., and `return BAR;` (or `return FOO;`) is only *evaluated* when you make a method call to `getOther()`, which is perfectly possible at that point since both enum constants are happily alive at that point.